# RSpec how to have should_receive check for call but let it run

Tags: ruby, rspec

In my RSpec I have:

```
discount.should_receive(:ended=).with(true)
```

In my model I have:

```
self.ended = document.at_css('#buy_now').blank?
  if not ended?
    ...
```

I want to check the `ended=` is called, but my spec would check it is called and then skip the actual update so the ended is not set properlyl.

I want it to actually run so subsequent logic would run correctly. Is there a way to do this, elegantly if possible?

Answer (score 1):

You could use an expect change to verify that ended was updated properly without preventing the actual update.

```
expect {
  # code which changes ended to true
}.to change(discount, :ended).from(false).to(true)
```

https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/2-0/docs/matchers/expect-change

Comment: that works thanks, I think I'll use this in this particular example. But I did face some other situations that merely doing change-expectaion is not enough and I must check the call has been made and actually make the call.